# Is there way to add normalization to conv2d in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, normalization, convolution

in order to do pattern matching properly convolutions require normalization
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation

unfortunately I can't find a way how to make input normalization for conv2d function.

is it hidden in implementation?

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.image.per_image_standardization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization) does exactly what you want.

> Linearly scales image to have zero mean and unit norm.
>
> This op computes (x - mean) / adjusted_stddev, where mean is the
>   average of all values in image, and adjusted_stddev = max(stddev,
>   1.0/sqrt(image.NumElements())).
>
> stddev is the standard deviation of all values in image. It is capped
>   away from zero to protect against division by 0 when handling uniform
>   images.

You need to do this normalization in a preprocessing step (similar to the place where you would do resizing). Also take a look at other [image-related functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Image_Adjustments).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mis-reading that, it's in the image library in TF 1.x:

`tf.image.per_image_standardization`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image

By the way, that particular function is a little annoying in that it only takes a single image as an input (3D), but you usually have a 4D tensor representing `[batch, height, width, channels]` for images. To apply that function to a batch of images you can do this:

`imgs4d = tf.map_fn(tf.image.per_image_standardization, imgs4d_float32)`

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, I was looking for tf.local_response_normalization (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn/normalization) for some strange reason it goes after conv2 layers and used not very often in examples

Comment: Ohhh, yeah, that's a different question than it sounded like. I don't know much about local response normalization, but I have the sense that batch normalization is a preferred approach to per-layer normalization. Interesting Q&A on it here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145768/importance-of-local-response-normalization-in-cnn
This is not input normalization though, this is normalizing the output of each layer.

Comment: as I understand batch or image normalization would work if input image is good exposed, for unevenly exposed images local response normalization is preferred