# How to make a customized tf.nn.conv2d() of TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, convolution

Almost same as existing conv2d(), but I would like to add a special function to it.

Suppose that we have a shape of 5x5 filter and a shape of 100x100 input.

In my understanding, conv2d() internally does:

1. choosing a 5x5 input area from the entire input.
2. calculating convolution between the 5x5 input area and the filter.
3. moving onto the next input area by a given strides.

In contrast, customized_conv2d() internally wants to do:

1. choosing a 5x5 input area from the entire input. (same)
2. subtracting a scalar value of f(5x5 input area) from each value in the 5x5 input area. (added)
3. calculating convolution between the subtracted values of the 5x5 input area and the filter. (same)
4. moving onto the next input area by a given strides. (same)

where f(x) is (max(x) + min(x)) / 2

- Is it easy to make it?
- Is the customized code able to run on a GPU?

Browsing relevant source codes of nn_ops.py, gen_nn_ops.py, and nn_ops.cc, I come to ask for your help.

Thanks in advance!

**APPENDED:**

What I have learned so far:

1) The easiest way for running on CPU might be to make customized TensorFlow. Tweak, as less as possible, [tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc) and [tensorflow/core/kernels/deep_conv2d.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/deep_conv2d.cc). With this special TensorFlow, conv2d() behaves in a desired way, instead of original one. Adding a new op, such as customized_conv2d(), by duplicating relevant lines and renaming all functions/methods from python wrapper to c++ code could be excessive efforts in this case.

2) No hope for running on GPU through CUDA. It seems that conv2d() of TensorFlow eventually calls [cudnnConvolutionForward()](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#cudnnConvolutionForward) in the NVIDIA CUDA Deep Neural Network library (cuDNN). Primary part of conv2d() is done in this library. [Software License Agreement (SLA) for NVIDIA cuDNN](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-sla/index.html) does not allow reverse engineering or modification. No source code of the library is provided.

3) There might be another hope for running on GPU through OpenCL, though.

Comment: So basically you wanna subtract a scalar value before doing the convolution, am I right? If so, you have to code a new conv2d, and I think it's very easy. You just need to do what you described before. However, I would not expect is gonna run as fast as the original convolution since as far as I know it's coded in C and python is just a wrapper. If you make this custom convolution function and you want to make it as fast as the original one (I guess that's why you ask about the GPU) it would take more time.

Comment: @kuonb, you got a point! Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700282/is-there-way-to-add-normalization-to-conv2d-in-tensorflow

Comment: @WendingPeng, thank you for the link. That applies normalization to the entire input values at once while what we would like to do here is to apply sort of normalization to the current small moving 5x5 patch area. I will follow your comments next time. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

Since convolution itself is linear, inserting any linear operation can be done by doing convolution via `tf.nn.conv2d` first and then that operation.

The `(max(x) + min(x)) / 2` on each `5x5` patch can be realized by `(tf.nn.max_pool(x) - tf.nn.max_pool(-x)) * 0.5`. To subtract this after conv, you also need to multiple the results by corresponding sums of convolution kernels. After that, you may apply the nonlinear activation function.

However, in general I don't know how to efficiently add nonlinear operations, e.g. get z-score for each `5x5` patch before convolutional multiplication. Perhaps other answers could provide some insights.

Comment: That's great! **(a)** Use of `max_pool` with a kernel size of 5x5 and stride values of (1, 1), and padding same yields f(x). **(b)** Applying `avg_pool` to the filter with the same parameters multiplied by 5 x 5 yields a sum of 5x5 patch of the filter. **(c)** Multiplying (a) and (b) element by element brings us how much we should subtract. Lastly, subtract (c) from the output of `conv2d`. Am I on the right track?